# Python dataframe, compare the value of two columns

Tags: python

The scoreA is the score for studentA and scoreB is for student B. I try to compare their score.

How can I compare scoreA and score B? can np.where do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df["winner"] = df.apply(lambda x: x[0] if x[2] > x[3] else x[1], axis=1)
```

Comment: and what about if studenA and studentB have the same score?

Answer (score 0):

check it

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('score.csv',delimiter=',')
df["STUDENT_WINNER"] = df.apply(lambda x: x[0] if x[2] > x[3] else ( 'EQUAL' if x[2] == x[3] else x[1]), axis=1)
print(df.head())
```